# Zero is always a Superfluous submodule.

Tags: ring-theory, modules, d-modules

**Definition:-1** A submodule $N$ of a  module $M$  is said to be superfluous (or small) if there is no proper submodule  $K$ of  $M$ such that $M=N+K$.

**Definition:-2** Jacobson radical $J(M)$ of a  module $M$ is the sum of all superfluous submodules of $M$.

I have a confusion about the trivial case. Clearly, zero submodule of every nonzero module is superfluous.  But when $M=0$ then $J(M) =0$. From these notions, i think $0$ should be a superfluous submodule of $0$. Please clear my doubt.
I will be highly thankful to You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0$ is also a superfluous submodule of $M=0$, because for all proper submodules $K\subsetneq M$, we have $0+K\ne 0$.

Comment: But, I find everywhere that zero submodule of  every nonzero module is superfluous.

Comment: @nirbhaykumar because nobody cares about the case you’re worried about, I guess.

Comment: @nirbhaykumar The definition you have given has $0$ superfluous. Wikipedia's too, for instance. I don't know about the sources you mention: you may want to check theirs.